# Maui app crash on IOS with 'Window was already deactivated'

Tags: ios, maui

Launching app with attached debbuger. Moving the app in background the app crash with following error:

```
[0:] An error occurred: 'Window was already deactivated'. Callstack: '   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Window.Microsoft.Maui.IWindow.Deactivated()
   at Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents.AppHostBuilderExtensions.<>c.<OnConfigureLifeCycle>b__2_4(UIApplication app)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiUIApplicationDelegate.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<OnResignActivation>b__0(OnResignActivation del)
   at Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents.LifecycleEventServiceExtensions.InvokeLifecycleEvents[OnResignActivation](IServiceProvider services, Action`1 action)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiUIApplicationDelegate.OnResignActivation(UIApplication application)
   at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(Int32 argc, String[] argv, IntPtr principalClassName, IntPtr delegateClassName) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:line 58
   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main(String[] args, Type principalClass, Type delegateClass) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:line 94
   at CFFTCheckInMobile.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\CheckInMobile\CheckInMobile\Platforms\iOS\Program.cs:line 13
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InterpretedInvoke_Method(Object obj, IntPtr* args)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span`1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)'
The app has been terminated.
```

After the error, the app restart and then the error never appear.

Platforms\iOS\Program.cs ha the following code:

```
public class Program
{
    // This is the main entry point of the application.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
        // you can specify it here.
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, typeof(AppDelegate));
    }
}
```

The app.xaml.cs has the following code

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static readonly Api Api = new();
    public static readonly Functions Functions = new();
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
                    
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoadingPage());
    }
```

The loadingpage has a viewmodel with following code:

```
public async Task LoadingTask()
{
    try
    {
        using (await loading.Show())
        {
            .............

            ((App)Application.Current).MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage(true));

        }            
    }
```

When i try to move the app in background the app is showing "MainPage"

The "await loading.Show()" is using mopups

Any ideas ?

Removing the code "((App)Application.Current).MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage(true));"
but nothing change.

Comment: Have you tried on a iOS physical device?

Comment: Yes, im using an iphone

Comment: I see you are using third party nuget Mopups. Will it still happen if you do not use it?